# When application is behind the VPN IPSec, How can I connect it through my iPhone application?

Tags: iphone, vpn

I am making iPhone application for accessing bugzilla (application).
Rightnow my application is allow to access bugzilla from anywhere without VPN IPSec, but whenever some bugzilla's required VPN IPsec authentication to use from outside the network, 
It will not allow to access bugzilla from my iPhone application,
how can I code to configure VPN first then connect to bugzilla?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't any programmatic access to the VPN system on the iPhone so you can do it in your application. If the question is if it can be done at all on the iPhone the answer is yes though since the iPhone itself does support VPN with ipsec. The user would need to set that up and activate it before trying to connect using the application.

Comment: Yes, there is VPN settings in iPhone.
So u mean if we configure VPN settings there, then there is no need for extra coding in our iPhone application to access the VPN?

Comment: As long as the user activates the VPN before using your app you are good to go. I'm saying you can't activate the VPN connection in your application, the user has to do it. There are security issues related to allowing applications to start and stop VPNs so I wouldn't expect it to be something they ever allow.

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look at the [existing application](http://www.ibzilla.com/blog) for accessing Bugzilla on iPhone.